# Setting .environment variables in node app, dynamically?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have an application for the tenant-based model. Super admin, Business user, and end user. To set up social profiles on our platform, we are allowing the Business user to enter sensitive information. For it, I have to change .environment variables (values varies for the user to user) from the node application.

Please guide me.

Comment: Not the way to go.

Comment: What would be an alternative approach, you recommend?

Comment: You have multiple users each storing data you dont want the other to see. Why not store the data in a database? If the information is sensitive then encrypt it. Environment variables are for system configuration information for the application itself and not for user data.

Comment: Valid, suggestion I guess.

Comment: you should never make assumptions about your platform. it is not scalable, what happens when you go serverless or you try to break your monolith in mycro services? your approach would be a problem. i think a better approach would be to use a memory key pair db like rediss to set your data in with a very small ttl that way it can be accessible to every service on your platform w/o compromising your scalability

Comment: as others suggested it is not an ideal way for what you're trying to do but still in case you need it for some other use case in future you can use [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to env variables from command line

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon, actually plan is to goahead with serverless architecture only.

Comment: Finally, I decided to opt for storing in database only. Albeit, thinking to use some encryption algorithms while storing and retrieving.